# R: Error in `[.default`(x, , i): Incorrect number of dimensions

Tags: r, taxonomy, vegan

I'm trying to use `taxondive` package to compare the taxonomic diversity of spiders from Oonopidae family in 11 different sites.

Unfortunately, I'm having troubles by create a object, which is a classification table with the taxonomic distances.

R console bring me a following message:
"Error in `[.default`(x, , i): Incorrect number of dimensions."

My data frame "spiderTaxon":

|  | genus | family | superfamily order |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Escaphiella_sp | Escaphiella | oonopidae | Dysderoidea |
| Gamasomorpha_sp | Gamasomorpha | oonopidae | Dysderoidea |
| Gamasomorphinae-sp | Gamasomorphinae | oonopidae | Dysderoidea |
| Hexapopha_sp1 | Hexapopha | oonopidae | Dysderoidea |
| Hexapopha_sp2 | Hexapopha | oonopidae | Dysderoidea |
| Hexapopha_sp3 | Hexapopha | oonopidae | Dysderoidea |
| Neotrops_sp | Neotrops | oonopidae | Dysderoidea |
| Neoxyphinus | Neoxyphinus | oonopidae | Dysderoidea |
| Neoxyphinus_A | Neoxyphinus | oonopidae | Dysderoidea |
| Neoxyphinus_sp1 | Neoxyphinus | oonopidae | Dysderoidea |
| Neoxyphinus_sp2 | Neoxyphinus | oonopidae | Dysderoidea |
| Neoxyphinus_sp3 | Neoxyphinus | oonopidae | Dysderoidea |
| Neoxyphinus_sp4 | Neoxyphinus | oonopidae | Dysderoidea |
| Neoxyphinus_sp5 | Neoxyphinus | oonopidae | Dysderoidea |
| Neoxyphinus_sp6 | Neoxyphinus | oonopidae | Dysderoidea |
| Predatoroonops_sp | Predatoroonops | oonopidae | Dysderoidea |
| Simlops_sp | Simlops | oonopidae | Dysderoidea |
| Triaeris_stenaspis | Triaeris stenaspis | oonopidae | Dysderoidea |

My data frame "abund":

|  | Escaphiella_sp | Gamasomorpha_sp | Gamasomorphinae-sp | Hexapopha_sp1 | Hexapopha_sp2 | Hexapopha_sp3 | Neotrops_sp | Neoxyphinus | Neoxyphinus_A | Neoxyphinus_sp1 | Neoxyphinus_sp2 | Neoxyphinus_sp3 | Neoxyphinus_sp4 | Neoxyphinus_sp5 | Neoxyphinus_sp6 | Predatoroonops_sp | Simlops_sp | Triaeris_stenaspis |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| alto_caparao | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| cariacica | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 7 | 0 | 0 | 4 | 0 | 0 |
| chapada_guimaraes | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 6 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| chapada_parecis | 0 | 0 | 6 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| chapada_veadeiros | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| ducke | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 7 | 5 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 5 | 0 |
| itamaraju | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 31 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| linhares | 7 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 7 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| reserva_campina | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| santa_teresa | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 5 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| taruma_mirim | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 5 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

There is the script I'm running:

```
library(vegan)
## Preliminary: needs better data and some support functions
abund<-read.csv("oonopidaeABUND.csv", h=T, row.names = 1)
spiderTaxon<-read.csv("Oonopidae.taxon.csv", header = TRUE, row.names = 1)

# Taxonomic distances from a classification table with variable step lengths.
taxdis <- taxa2dist(spiderTaxon, varstep = FALSE, check = TRUE, labels)
plot(hclust(taxdis), hang = -1)
```

There is the message from console:

```
> ## Preliminary: needs better data and some support functions
> abund<-read.csv("oonopidaeABUND.csv", h=T, row.names = 1)
> spiderTaxon<-read.csv("Oonopidae.taxon.csv", header = TRUE, row.names = 1)
> # Taxonomic distances from a classification table with variable step lengths.
> taxdis <- taxa2dist(spiderTaxon, varstep = FALSE, check = TRUE, labels)
Error in `[.default`(x, , i): Incorrect number of dimensions
```

I tried to figure out the solutions before, by I wasn't well succeeded.

Could someone help me understand this, please?

I thank you all.

Comment: what do you have as `labels`?? You have already used `row.names = 1` in `read.csv` you do not need the `labels` any more. Try doing `taxdis <- taxa2dist(spiderTaxon, varstep = FALSE, check = TRUE)`

Comment: I don't know how important this is for your problem, but `taxa2dist` will not give you much information: you only have one family (Oonopidae) and below that only two levels: genus and species. This also means that you only have one step (branch) in your tree. The ubiquitous levels (family and superfamily) are just disregarded. It may be that throwing out two or more constant classes fails, but to check that, remove the uppermost constant levels (only one class value) and see if that helps. If that's the case, I'll fix it in vegan.

Comment: Thank you, Mr @Onyambu. It didn't work. But you're right, i didn't need to use the `labels`. The next answer solved the problem. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, Dr. @JariOksanen. I was doing a preliminary data analysis, while not receiving confirmation of the data for the other spider families. So I used this data only with Oonopidae - data that I had available at the time. In fact, it doesn't make much sense to use just one family to see the range of taxonomic diversity, my fault. Because of that, I already expected a simplified value. As I had this problem, I was concerned about not being able to use the full data in the future. So I tried to understand what was going on first of all. [...]

Comment: [...] I followed your advice and removed the uppermost constant levels, and the same error message appeared. Then, I changed some of the values ​​in the database: I added a new level (suborder); and at each level I made sure I had more than one class (more than one family, superfamily, and suborder). This worked. Therefore, I conclude that it is necessary that there be more than one different value at each taxonomic level. I sincerely thank you very much for your time Dr. @JariOksanen. I learned a lot. This exchange of experiences here is a hidden gem. Best regards, from Brazil.

Comment: The behaviour of the function is now fixed in github.